# Python GitLab How to get all file names in a project?

Tags: python, git, api, gitlab

I want to get all files ( python files esp ) in a git project. While I am able to access one file at a time, based on file name input. I am unsure how to get all file names under a directory.

My present code below

```
gl=gitlab.Gitlab('https://git.sys.xxx.com', private_token=pwd, api_version=4)
gl.auth()
project=gl.projects.get('hadoop-d/xyz')
a='src/main/python/xyz_inbound/baseline/*.*'
b='file_name'
c='.py'
d=a+b+c
f=project.files.get(file_path=d, ref='master')
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this command from [here](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/projects.html?highlight=files#project-files)

```
# list the content of the root directory for the default branch
items = project.repository_tree()

# list the content of a subdirectory on a specific branch
items = project.repository_tree(path='docs', ref='branch1')
```

I think for your usecase you'll need something like the following:

```
items = project.repository_tree(path='src/main/python/xyz_inbound/baseline',
                                ref='master', recursive=True, all=True)
filenames = [f.path for f in items if f.path[-3:] == '.py']
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a list of the files, then you can use the [repositories API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#list-repository-tree) to get a list of files and filter for the files in a particular repository.

As explained in the docs, the repository tree endpoint is essentially the same as running `git ls-tree` on the repo.

Comment: thank you, I am pretty new to this. The documention is not in python code or Gitlab API. Could you point me to python code? 
The current path is this all files are in baseline folder and I need to access that.

https://git.sys.xxx.com/hadoop-d/xyz/src/main/python/xyz_inbound/baseline/file1.py

Comment: "not in python code or Gitlab APi" I'm not sure what you mean by this since my link is literally to the GitLab API docs. Unfortunately, I'm not too familiar with Python so wouldn't be able to give you the exact code, but most likely you'll need to do it in 2 parts. Part 1 is get the data. Part 2 is filter for the directory you want.